# how to get html source code in android?

Tags: android

What would the best approach to :

1. get html codes by calling url and displaying it in some views
2. if i would be editing the values against title tag, it must be automatically updated in the url link?

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the JSoup cookbook.

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/

This has a lot of good information in it and should be able to answer most of your questions.

You are probably looking for something along the lines of this: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-body-fragment